# Excel 2013 VBA adding strange quotes

Tags: vba, excel, quotes

Let say

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "html"
    Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 2).Value = "<xml xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" > "
    txt = "                   '" & Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 1) & "'=>array('" & Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 2) & "' => $" & Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 1) & "),"
    MsgBox txt
    FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\array.txt"
    Open FilePath For Output As #2
    Write #2, txt
    Close #2
End Sub
```

Now compare msgbox output with array.txt file.

So all my txt string became quoted, also added additional quotes to url, how to prevent changes and get string as it is.

Question is how to put msgbox output in array.txt ?

Comment: you want one double quote in the text file rather then a doubled?

Comment: Please clarify your question by adding expected and actual output.

Comment: Try `& Chr(34) &` where you want quotes in the string?

Comment: `Write` quotes the String. Use `Print` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 1).Value = "html"
    Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 2).Value = "<xml xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" > "
    txt = "                   '" & Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 1) & "'=>array('" & Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 2) & "' => $" & Worksheets("1").Cells(1, 1) & "),"
    MsgBox txt
    FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\array.txt"
    Open FilePath For Output As #2
    Print #2, txt
    Close #2
End Sub
```